# Aws Api gateway Unable to load fast api swagger docs page

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, fastapi

I have deployed a simple fast api to  aws API gateway .All the end points working fine however i am unable to load the swagger docs page I see below error

[image]

**Api Code:**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from mangum import Mangum
import os
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
stage = os.environ.get('STAGE', None)
openapi_prefix = f"/{stage}" if stage else "/"
app = FastAPI(title="MyAwesomeApp",root_path="stage")


@app.get("/")
def get_root():
    return {"message": "FastAPI running in a Lambda function"}


@app.get("/info")
def get_root():
    return {"message": "TestInfo"}


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
handler = Mangum(app)
```

I tried adding the root as mentioned below
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/
Any help on this will be appreciated .

Comment: I'm having the same problem. But in my case sometime it works but most of the time it fail to load the API docs.

Comment: same problem reported on Github https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2787

Comment: Hey man! I solved it. In my case that was because my AWS lambda function time out is too short 3 seconds!!!. I updated it to 30 seconds and the API docs works as expected.
Refer this one: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-lambda-task-timed-out-after-seconds

Comment: I figured it out by enable CloudWatch for the Gateway. And It showed the exact error for me. Maybe your case is a little different. Please enable it and check for the error

Comment: I found the solution we need to add root_path="/dev" while creating fast api app .This root path should be same as the api gatway stage but with fastapi versioning this does not work

Comment: @qangdev are you using api versioning of fast api by using fastapi_versioning or without that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution we need to add `root_path="/dev"` like `app = FastAPI(title=settings.NAME,root_path="/dev")`
while creating fast api app .This root path should be same as the api gatway stage name .
However this approach does not work if you are using fastapi versioning

Comment: But the docs is not working if I ran the code locally when we put `root_path=/dev`. `Fetch error Not Found /dev/openapi.json`.